# Restcomm GLMC diameter setup

Tags: restcomm, diameter-protocol

I'm new to diameter protocol. All I want to do is provide a method to our developers to get mobile location using diameter protocol. We are still using map ati over sigtran to request location info, but it's no longer valid since LTE.

I have installed RestComm GLMC
`https://github.com/RestComm/gmlc`

and configured 
`jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/restcomm-diameter-mux-1.7.0.sar/config/jdiameter-config.xml` as below since I want to connect to HSS.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration xmlns="http://www.jdiameter.org/jdiameter-server">

  <LocalPeer>
    <URI value=""aaa://uas.restcomm.org:3868"" />
    <!-- URI value="aaa://restcomm.open-ims.test:1812" /--> <!-- OpenIMS Example -->
    <IPAddresses>
      <IPAddress value="127.0.0.1" />
    </IPAddresses>
    <Realm value="MY_RELM_NAME" />
    <!-- Realm value="open-ims.test" / --> <!-- OpenIMS Example -->
    <VendorID value="193" />
    <ProductName value="jDiameter" />
    <FirmwareRevision value="1" />
    <OverloadMonitor>
      <Entry index="1" lowThreshold="0.5" highThreshold="0.6">
        <ApplicationID>
          <VendorId value="193" />
          <AuthApplId value="0" />
          <AcctApplId value="19302" />
        </ApplicationID>
      </Entry>
    </OverloadMonitor>
  </LocalPeer>

  <Parameters>
    <AcceptUndefinedPeer value="true" />
    <DuplicateProtection value="false" />
    <DuplicateTimer value="240000" />
    <DuplicateSize value="5000" />
    <UseUriAsFqdn value="false" /> <!-- Needed for Ericsson Emulator (set to true) -->
    <QueueSize value="10000" />
    <MessageTimeOut value="60000" />
    <StopTimeOut value="10000" />
    <CeaTimeOut value="10000" />
    <IacTimeOut value="30000" />
    <DwaTimeOut value="10000" />
    <DpaTimeOut value="5000" />
    <RecTimeOut value="10000" />

    <!-- Peer FSM Thread Count Configuration -->
    <PeerFSMThreadCount value="3" />

    <!-- Statistics Configuration -->
    <Statistics pause="30000" delay="30000" enabled="false" active_records="Concurrent,ScheduledExecService,Network,ScheduledExecService,AppGenRequestPerSecond,NetGenRequestPerSecond,Peer,Peer.local,PeerFSM"/>

    <Concurrent>
      <Entity name="ThreadGroup" size="64"/> <!-- Common Thread Pool -->
      <Entity name="ProcessingMessageTimer" size="1"/>
      <Entity name="DuplicationMessageTimer" size="1"/>
      <Entity name="RedirectMessageTimer" size="1"/>
      <Entity name="PeerOverloadTimer" size="1"/>
      <Entity name="ConnectionTimer" size="1"/>
      <Entity name="StatisticTimer" size="1"/>
    </Concurrent>

    <Dictionary enabled="false" sendLevel="MESSAGE" receiveLevel="OFF" />    

    <!-- Router Request Table Cache Size and ClearSize -->
    <RequestTable size="10240" clear_size="2048" />

  </Parameters>

  <Network>
    <Peers>
      <!-- Testsuite -->
      <Peer name="aaa://HSS_IP:3868" attempt_connect="true" rating="1" />

      <!-- Ericsson SDK Client -->
      <!-- Peer name="aaa://127.0.0.1:11812" attempt_connect="false" rating="1"/-->

      <!-- Ericsson SDK Emulator -->
      <!-- Peer name="aaa://127.0.0.1:21812" attempt_connect="true" rating="1" /-->

      <!-- Sh / CCA / Cx/Dx -->
      <!-- Peer name="aaa://uac.restcomm.org" attempt_connect="false" rating="1" /-->

      <!-- Sh (OpenIMS) -->
      <!-- Peer name="aaa://hss.open-ims.test" attempt_connect="true" rating="1" /-->
    </Peers>
    <Realms>
      <!-- Ericsson SDK Client/Emulator and Testsuite -->
      <Realm name="MY_RELM_NAME" peers="HSS_IP_1,HSS_IP_2" local_action="LOCAL" dynamic="false" exp_time="1">
        <ApplicationID>
          <VendorId value="193" />
          <AuthApplId value="0" />
          <AcctApplId value="19302" />
        </ApplicationID>
      </Realm>

      <!-- Sh -->
      <!-- Realm name="restcomm.org" peers="127.0.0.1" local_action="LOCAL" dynamic="false" exp_time="1">
        <ApplicationID>
          <VendorId value="10415" />
          <AuthApplId value="16777217" />
          <AcctApplId value="0" />
        </ApplicationID>
      </Realm-->

      <!-- Sh (OpenIMS) -->
      <!-- Realm name="open-ims.test" peers="hss.open-ims.test,restcomm.open-ims.test" local_action="LOCAL" dynamic="false" exp_time="1">
        <ApplicationID>
          <VendorId value="10415" />
          <AuthApplId value="16777217" />
          <AcctApplId value="0" />
        </ApplicationID>
      </Realm-->

      <!--  CCA -->
      <!-- Realm name="restcomm.org" peers="127.0.0.1" local_action="LOCAL" dynamic="false" exp_time="1">
        <ApplicationID>
          <VendorId value="0" />
          <AuthApplId value="4" />
          <AcctApplId value="0" />
        </ApplicationID>
      </Realm -->

      <!-- Cx/Dx -->
      <!-- Realm name="restcomm.org" peers="127.0.0.1" local_action="LOCAL" dynamic="false" exp_time="1">
        <ApplicationID>
          <VendorId value="10415" />
          <AuthApplId value="16777216" />
          <AcctApplId value="0" />
        </ApplicationID>
      </Realm-->
    </Realms>
  </Network>

  <Extensions>
    <!-- To enable clustering uncomment the following lines
    <SessionDatasource value="org.mobicents.diameter.impl.ha.data.ReplicatedSessionDatasource"/>
    <TimerFacility value="org.mobicents.diameter.impl.ha.timer.ReplicatedTimerFacilityImpl"/>
    -->
  </Extensions>

</Configuration>
```

New I start the jboss server using below command
`./run.sh -bMY_IP -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=52297,suspend=n,server=y`

After it's started, when I do a curl request `curl -X POST http://MY_IP:8080/restcomm/gmlc/rest?msisdn=MY_MSISDN` to get location of a specific MSISDN I get below error as a return

`<html><head><title>JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 501 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server does not support the functionality needed to fulfill this request ().</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA</h3></body></html>[root@eir1apps ~]#`

and below in jboss log

`19:07:02,411 WARN  [SccpRoutingControl] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-4-thread-1) Received SccpMessage for Translation but no matching Rule found for local routing
SccpMessage=Sccp Msg [Type=-1 networkId=0 sls=1 incomingOpc=-1 incomingDpc=-1 outgoingDpc=-1 CallingAddress(pc=0,ssn=145,AI=18,gt=GlobalTitle0100Impl [digits=628184422892, natureOfAddress=INTERNATIONAL, numberingPlan=ISDN_TELEPHONY, translationType=0, encodingScheme=BCDEvenEncodingScheme[type=BCD_ODD, code=2]]) CalledParty(pc=0,ssn=6,AI=18,gt=GlobalTitle0100Impl [digits=MY_MSISDN, natureOfAddress=INTERNATIONAL, numberingPlan=ISDN_TELEPHONY, translationType=0, encodingScheme=BCDOddEncodingScheme[type=BCD_ODD, code=1]]) DataLen=78]
19:08:02,420 ERROR [MobileCoreNetworkInterfaceSbb] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-3-thread-1)
Rx :  onDialogTimeout DialogTimeout [org.mobicents.slee.resource.map.service.mobility.wrappers.MAPDialogMobilityWrapper@3999406a]
19:08:02,420 WARN  [MobileCoreNetworkInterfaceSbb] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-3-thread-1) When responding to HTTP no pending HTTP request is found, responseData=DialogTimeout
19:10:56,085 WARN  [SccpRoutingControl] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-6-thread-1) Received SccpMessage for Translation but no matching Rule found for local routing
SccpMessage=Sccp Msg [Type=-1 networkId=0 sls=2 incomingOpc=-1 incomingDpc=-1 outgoingDpc=-1 CallingAddress(pc=0,ssn=145,AI=18,gt=GlobalTitle0100Impl [digits=628184422892, natureOfAddress=INTERNATIONAL, numberingPlan=ISDN_TELEPHONY, translationType=0, encodingScheme=BCDEvenEncodingScheme[type=BCD_ODD, code=2]]) CalledParty(pc=0,ssn=6,AI=18,gt=GlobalTitle0100Impl [digits=MY_MSISDN, natureOfAddress=INTERNATIONAL, numberingPlan=ISDN_TELEPHONY, translationType=0, encodingScheme=BCDOddEncodingScheme[type=BCD_ODD, code=1]]) DataLen=78]`

Now I'm stuck here. I have no idea if this is a configuration issue or not

Answer (score 1):

@ivcode we don't support Diameter in GMLC yet. There is ongoing work on that happening. Would you like to help contribute to the effort ?

Comment: I would be happy to help

Comment: Great ! can you sign the Contributor License Agreement at https://telestax.com/open-source/#Contribute and I'll get back to you over email !